# devextreme dxTreeView clearSelection

Tags: knockout.js, treeview, devextreme

I am using devextreme dxTreeView , I want a clear selection function to uncheck current selection.

```
self.SubViewModel = {
    treeViewOptions: {
        items: Stores,
        dataStructure: "plain",
        showCheckBoxesMode: true,
        searchValue: self.PackSearch,
        parentIdExpr: "Key",
        keyExpr: "ID",
        displayExpr: "Name",
        selectionMode: "single",
        expandAllEnabled: true,
        expandeExpr: "expanded",
        expandNodesRecursive: true,
    }
};
```

[image: tree with checked box]

Comment: Have you tried anything? Can you create a snippet in the question or through jsfiddle - to show how it works right now?

Answer (score 0):

This is a *jquery* solution https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T221422/dxtreeview-clearselection

```
function clearSelection() {
    treeView.beginUpdate();
    $.each(treeView.option('items'), function() { 
        treeView.unselectItem(this); 
    });
    treeView.endUpdate();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

w.r.to ko and DevExtreme you need to add an observable to manage such things

```
    "id": "1_1",
    "text": "Super Mart of the West",
    "expanded": true,
    "selected": variable which is observable,
```

You can add **"selected": ko.observable()** and reset the value to false on your click event by iterating self.SubViewModel.treeViewOptions.items recursively.

Tip: mentioning "selected" key in your items object you may not be able to achieve any custom selections other than any others are provided.

Answer (score 0):

**The Official Way**

1. You can use `getSelectedNodeKeys` methods for getting to all key which is selected
2. Then use `unselectItem` methods for unselect all selected node keys

Find the documentation here for [getSelectedNodeKeys](https://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/ApiReference/UI_Components/dxTreeView/Methods/#getSelectedNodeKeys) And [unselectItem](https://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/ApiReference/UI_Components/dxTreeView/Methods/#getSelectedNodeKeys)

And the other way with jQuery if the data structure is plain (in your case it is): alternatively you just clear selected (which is written `selectedExpr`) from `dataSource` or `items`

```
const element = $(".treeElement");
const items = element.option("items");
element.option("items",items.map(o => {
     o.selected = false
}));
```